# How do i fill up textbox from database in asp.net visual studio without id?

Tags: asp.net

I am trying to get details of an account in a row using the Username instead of id. I have limited knowledge on this matter so im only stuck with the code that i learned in class.

I have tried changing variables, but probably wont help and the code i have provided below, would not retrieve any data from the database...
(Username are retrieved from previous page and yes it did show up in this page)

This is the code used on previous page: (code is placed on a button)

```
string username = Session["Username"].ToString();
            Response.Redirect("EditAccountDetail.aspx?Username="+ username);

private DataTable GetData()
        {
            string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
            {
                using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Guest"))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                    {
                        cmd.Connection = con;
                        sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                        using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                        {
                            sda.Fill(dt);
                            return dt;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the code im working on right now:

```
    String Uname = Request.QueryString["Username"];


    string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Guest WHERE Username='" + Uname+"'"))
        {
            using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
            {
                cmd.Connection = con;
                sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    sda.Fill(dt);

                    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                    {
                        string id = row["Id"].ToString();
                        string Full_name = row["Full_name"].ToString();
                        string Username = row["Username"].ToString();
                        string Password = row["Password"].ToString();
                        string Email = row["Email"].ToString();
                        string DOB = row["DOB"].ToString();
                        string Gender = row["Gender"].ToString();


                        this.HiddenField1.Value = id;
                        this.TextBox_Name.Text = Full_name;
                        this.TextBox_Username.Text = Username;
                        this.TextBox_Password.Text = Password;
                        this.TextBox_Email.Text = Email;
                        this.TextBox_DOB.Text = DOB;
                        this.RadioButtonList_Gender.Text = Gender;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

This is the code in the button:

    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["myDbConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

                try
                {

                    string query = "UPDATE Guest SET Full_name=@Full_name, Username=@Username, Password=@Password, Email=@Email, DOB=@DOB, Gender=@Gender WHERE Id=@id";

                    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", HiddenField1.Value);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Full_name", TextBox_Name.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Username", TextBox_Username.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Password", TextBox_Password.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", TextBox_Email.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DOB", TextBox_DOB.Text);
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Gender", RadioButtonList_Gender.Text);


                    con.Open();
                    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                    Response.Redirect("GuestMenu.aspx");
                    con.Close();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    Response.Write("Error: " + ex.ToString());
                }
```

Comment: please check if you are actually getting a row from the database with the select query by placing a breakpoint in your code.

Comment: @GaganDeep im not sure how that work but this code actually work from my other page but using Id instead of Username

Comment: Right Click on sda.Fill(dt);-->Breakpoint-->Insert Breakpoint. Then hit F5 to start debugging your code, use F10 to step forward into your code once you reach the breakpoint. See if your code goes inside the foreach loop.

Comment: @GaganDeep I tried it, didn't understand how it work but i include more code to give more details.

Comment: Could you paste the URL which your address bar shows after you are redirected to the EditAccountDetail.aspx Page. also please show the snapshot of the table having the data of the specific username which you are passing as QS.

Comment: @GaganDeep  OMG thanks for mentioning that... i just realised i redirect to a wrong aspx file... the problem is solved... thank you thank you its suppose to be EditProfile.aspx

Comment: @GaganDeep http://localhost:63203/EditProfile?Username=Jack

Comment: hahaha great....

Answer (score 0):

If you are redirecting to the "GuestMenu" page, then you have to add username in the query string so that you can retrieve this on the page.

```
Response.Redirect("GuestMenu.aspx?Username="+TextBox_Username.Text);
```

Comment: What do you mean? i dont think i need that

Comment: As you are passing values from one page to another, so either you need session or query string to pass the data from one page to another.

Comment: Did you try "Trim()" method in the select query in case there are white spaces in the username, using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Guest WHERE Username='" + Uname.Trim()+"'"))

Answer (score -1):

By seeing your current code, you should be getting some error. Please post the error details if any.

You can try changing the query as below and check for database result

```
 new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Guest WHERE Username='" + Uname + "'")
```

Comment: thank you for that but it still wont retrieve data from the database to the textboxes

Comment: Did you check `String Uname = Request.QueryString["Username"];` code giving you the Username.

Comment: You are not passing any `QueryString` from your first page.

Comment: Actually it did. i add more code to explain more. see if u can see any problem